# IP Locator not working with Cloudflare

Tags: ip-address, geolocation

I have set up an IP Locator service. Worked fine, until I started using Cloudflare:

Instead of showing the user's IP address, Cloudflare shows its server's IP! What can I do?

My Site: http://nix-pix.co.uk/ip

**Note:** I'm on a shared server, so I cannot do any server-side modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed in one of several ways:

In PHP, Cloudflare reports the real IP addresses like this: `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];`

For a server-side solution, you can install a module which will automatically resolve the correct IP.  [Information about restoring original visitor IP with CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200038166-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-my-server-logs-).